# What is the most elegant way to insert this conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, tooltip

I would like to pass a variable to either cause this method by `click` or by `hover`.

Right now, it defaults to click.

```
    var defaults = {    
        xOffset: 10,        
        yOffset: 25,
        tooltipId: "easyTooltip",
        clickRemove: true,
        content: "",
        useElement: "",
        clickAppear: true
    }; 

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  
    var content;

$(this).click(function(e){
    $("#" + options.tooltipId).remove();                                                               
    content = (options.content != "") ? options.content : title;
    content = (options.useElement != "") ? $("#" + options.useElement).html() : content;
    $(this).attr("title","");                                                   
    if (content != "" && content != undefined){         
        $("body").append("<div id='"+ options.tooltipId +"'>"+ content +"</div>");      
        $("#" + options.tooltipId)
            .css("position","absolute")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - options.yOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + options.xOffset) + "px")                     
            .css("display","none")
            .fadeIn("fast");
    return false;
    }
},
```

I want it to so that I could pass in the method call that `clickAppear = false` and in that case it would alternatively produce this:

```
$(this).hover(function(e){
  ...
```

Instead of copying and pasting the entire method twice in a conditional ( which didn't seem to work anyway ), I was wondering if there was an elegant way to write this conditional while keeping the block DRY.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not put all your code in a function and set that function as the callback for both `.click` and `.hover`?

Comment: Sounds clever, I'm just not sure what you're pointing at.

Comment: I agree with what Matt said. .click and .hover don't have to take anonymous functions. Just create a named function and then do the if clickappear and the appropriate binding.

Comment: What is `this` in context? Shouldn't that be `"a"`?

Comment: @Matt: Make it an answer and you've got a +1 from me. I would but I'd feel like I'm stealing your answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can just write:

```
$(this)[options.clickAppear ? "click" : "hover"](function(e) {
  // your code
});
```

That just checks the option and picks either the "click" or "hover" function, and calls it.

Comment: Ha ha.  Well it seemed pretty clear; sometimes the questions are not so clear or easy :-)

Comment: Guns so fast, I can't even mark this correct for another two minutes! Thanks Pointy! Excellent idea!

Comment: I hadn't thought about the fact that you can access functions on an object in that way. To the extent that it took me quite a while to work out what was happening here. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your handler function as a variable :

```
var myFunc = function(e){ // your handling code here
};
```

Then on your function that attach the handler to the events you put your condition:

```
if(options.clickAppear)
   $(elem).click(myFunc);
else
   $(elem).hover(myFunc);
```

Comment: The function could also be declared with `function myFunc(e) { ... }`

Comment: yeah or even more elegant put it in your defaults object.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a named function:

```
function doStuff() {
  ..
}

$(this).click(doStuff);
$(this).hover(doStuff);
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, this probably won't work as is because the first instance of `this` has no context -- and is therefore undefined. But this is the general idea:

```
$(this).click(function(e){
    // your method
}).hover(function(e){
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Kind of fails the "elegant" criteria.

Comment: While not the *most* elegant, it is more elegant that re-writing the method [which was the OP's criteria.]